Every finite subgroup of $GL_n(Q)$ is conjugated to a subgroup of $GL_n(R)$.
Claim: let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and $Q$ be its quotient field. Then every finite subgroup of $GL_n(Q)$ is conjugated to a subgroup of $GL_n(R)$.
So I want to solve this exercise but I really have no idea where to start (how to use the fact that $R$ is PID for example). I kinda see that the request for the subgroup to be finite is probably relevant to get a common denominator (gcd?) but it's just a qualitative observation. I would really appreciate some input (I'm not really asking for a full solution). Is any representation theory knowledge needed?

Don't know the answer offhand, by my intuition would be to look at the LCM of denominators in all entries. Perhaps start with some simple examples, like $R=\mathbf Z$ or a DVR like $\mathbf Z_{(p)}$.

Hint: start with $n=1$.

@MartinBrandenburg wait maybe I'm leading towards a weird direction but: if $n=1$ then for every $q \in Q$ then $q^{-1}Gq=G$ so the conjugacy classes are trivial. This is really weird, because this would require that every finite subgroup of $Q*$ is actually a subgroup of $R*$. I'll try to prove this but I am not really convinced about my own reasoning.

$G$ is acting on a vector space $V$ with basis $B$.  The $R$-submodule $M$ spanned by ${gb :g \in G, b \in B}$ is $G$-invariant. $M$ is torsion-free and hence (since $R$ is a PID) free.

@F13 Your approach for $n=1$ looks fine so far.

@MartinBrandenburg so I managed to prove that a finite PID is a field so in particular $R=Q$. This is obviously false for infinite ones (example: $\mathbb{Z}$), and in this case I'm finding it hard to come up with a simple answer.

Wait I may got it. Suppose $R$ is infinite, then also $Q$ is infinite because $R \subseteq Q$. Then consider $G \leq Q*$ and suppose that $G$ is finite and $q \in G \setminus R$. Then in particular $ \leq G$ so $q$ has finite order call that $n$. I have $q^n = 1 = q^{-n}$. Call $p = q^{-1}$ then $p^n = 1$ so $p \cdot p^{n-1} = 1$ so $q = p^{n-1} \in R$: contraddiction.

The subgroup $G \subseteq \mathrm{GL}_n(Q)$ can be seen as an action of $G$ on the vector space $Q^n$ over $Q$. Choose the standard basis $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ of $Q^n$. We may also regard $Q^n$ as an $R$-module, and it is torsionfree. Consider the $R$-submodule $M \subseteq Q^n$ generated by the $g e_i$ for $g \in G$, $1 \leq i \leq n$. It is a finitely generated torsionfree $R$-module, hence it is free (by the classification of f.g. modules over PIDs). Notice $M \otimes_R Q = Q^n$ (since it contains all $e_i$). This shows that the rank of $M$ over $R$ is $n$. Let's say $b_1,\dotsc,b_n$ is a basis of $M$ over $R$. Now $G$ also acts on $M$ by $R$-linear automorphisms. This means we get a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}_R(M) \cong \mathrm{GL}_n(R)$, let's say the image is $H \subseteq \mathrm{GL}_n(R)$. Define the $Q$-linear isomorphism $\sigma : Q^n \to Q^n$ by mapping $b_i \mapsto e_i$, or equivalently, $\sigma \in \mathrm{GL}_n(Q)$. Then $G = \sigma H \sigma^{-1}$.

Hi thank you very much for you answer and your time. This exercise is supposed to be solvable without involving modules and related theory. Anyways I'm curious about those things so I may start giving a look at these topics by myself
